# What function does this trigonometric series represent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions, trigonometric-series

I wonder what known function does this trigonometric series represent?

$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}}\sin{(kx)}
$$
with 
$$
-\pi\le x\le \pi 
$$
and
$$
f(x)=f(x+2\pi)
$$

And how is it obtained?

Here is a plot of two periods using 100 terms:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to find function (in form of combination elementary functions) from its fourier coefficients ?

Answer (score 1):

We may formally express the series in terms of the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) defined as $\displaystyle\text{Li}_p(z):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{z^k}{k^{p}}$. Since $\sin(kx)=\text{Im}\,(e^{ikx})$, this series is the imaginary part of the summation $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{ikx}}{k^{3/2}}$. Therefore we may write $\boxed{f(x)=\text{Im}\,\left[\text{Li}_{3/2}(e^{i x})\right]}$.

However, this formal approach is actually a bit careless: the definition of the polylog cited above only converges for $|z|<1$, which is equivalent to requiring $x$ to have positive imaginary part. I'll see if I can clear up this subtlety.

Comment: Also, per Wikipedia the series defined in the question is known as a Clausen function (specifically the $S$-type Clausen function of order $3/2$.) So for generic $x$ there's probably little to be said about it at an elementary level.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be a function of the form
$$y=A\sin\left[x-\left(\frac{\pi}2-\alpha\right)y\right]$$
where $A$ is the amplitude and $\alpha$ ($0<\alpha<\frac\pi2$) is the angle where the function is maximum.

See my response to another related question here:

[Skewed Trigonometric Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904135/skewed-trigonometric-function/908438#908438)